# Showing that the projective space is an n-manifold.

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, projective-space

I have to show that the real projective space $\mathbb{RP}^n$ is an n-manifold. I will use the set label $\mathbb{P}^n$ instead of $\mathbb{RP}^n$. $\mathbb{P}^n$ the set of all the lines passing through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and is equipped with the quotient topology induced by the quotient map $q: \mathbb{R^{n+1}}-{0} \to \mathbb{P}^n$. Here q takes each point in $\mathbb{R^{n+1}}-{0} $ to its span.

There are a few solutions available on the net but I have thought of a different way to do this. Please let me know if it is correct and how I can make it mathematically rigorous.

Now, the main part arrives. Consider the $\mathbb{R^2}$ plane and any line passing through the origin. Consider the lines $x=1$ and $y=1$. Any line through origin will cut intersect $x=1$ at one point or $y=1$ at one point. There is just one line through the origin that intersects both. We observe that if I define f: $\mathbb{P^1} \to \mathbb{R^2}$ such that f sends any element of $\mathbb{P^1}$ to the point on $x=1$ or $y=1$ where this element intersects it then f is an injection.

Now restrict the co-domain to just the lines $x=1$, $y=1$ (the wedge sum of these 2 lines and they meet at (1,1)). Then, the restricted f is surjective as well. So, it is a bijection now. Moreover, it seems continuous (However, I am not able to prove this). Even its inverse also seems continuous.

So, this f with its codomain restricted to this wedge sum should be a homeomorphism.

Now, consider again $x=1$ and $y=1$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$ and equip them with subspace topology. While considering the wedge sum of these, equip them with the disjoint union topology. Now, $x=1$ and $y=1$ are Hausdorff so their wedge sum is also Hausdorff. They are second countable as well. Now, for each point in this wedge sum, I can find a neighborhood which is homeomorphic to an open interval in R. So, this is locally euclidean of dimension 1. Hence, this wedge sum will be a 1-manifold. So, $\mathbb{P^1}$ will be a 1-manifold (since it is homeomorphic to this space). Then, I can do this thing in higher dimenision to conclude that $\mathbb{P^n}$ is a n-manifold.

Is this proof correct? If it is, then how do I make it mathematically rigorous?

Comment: You are using the charts $x=1$ and $y=1$. $\Bbb P^1$ is circle when they are glued.

Comment: Use one of the two lines at a time. The map from a point on $x=1$ to the line through that point and the origin is a coordinate chart. Do same for $y=1$.

Comment: This isn't a wedge sum if I understand you correctly as while the two lines you have drawn only intersect at one point the corresponding parts of $\mathbb{P}^1$ intersect everywhere except for two points. Or from another perspective your function $f$ is not well defined. Instead what you have is two overlapping charts which cover the whole space: exactly what you need for the definition of a manifold.

Comment: @Deane I understood now. Sorry, I messed it up a bit by bringing the 'wedge sum' thing. If I follow your suggestion, then I guess the problem is becoming very similar to the problem where to show that the $S^2$ is locally euclidean of dimension 2, I had to remove the north pole once, and then the south pole.

Comment: @Callum. I got it. I will remove this 'wedge sum' thing. Also, I found that there are just 2 lines which intersect only one of x=1 and y=1. So, as Deane suggested, if I take the x=1 line and y=1 one by one, then I should be able to show that this space, RP 1, is locally euclidean of dimenison 1. I guess extending it to higher dimenisons shouldn't be an issue after that. I will try to do so.

Comment: Yes, exactly. You clearly understood the essential idea but got a bit off track.